# npm run dev lanza error

Tags: vue.js

Luego de configurar mi archivo app.js en resources/assets/, cuando corro en la consola npm run dev me lanza este error:

```
ERROR in ./resources/assets/js/app.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/xampp/htdocs/logismart/resources         
/assets/js/app.js: Unexpected token, expected , (30:15)

 28 |
 29 |     data: {
> 30 |          vehiculos []
    |                    ^
 31 |     },
 32 |     methods: {
 33 |          getvehiculos function() {

 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack    
 /bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-   
 mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
 npm ERR! Exit status 2
 npm ERR!
 npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely   
 additional logging output above.
```

Mi archivo app.js está como sigue
    require('./bootstrap');

```
window.Vue = require('vue'); 

const app = new Vue({

el: '#crud',         

created: function(){
    this.getvehiculos();
},

data: {
    vehiculos []
},
methods: {
    getvehiculos function() {

        var urlprueba = 'choferes';
        axios.get(urlprueba).then(response =>{
        this.vehiculos = response.data
        }) 
    }
},


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te faltan los dos puntos para declarar la propiedad vehiculos como array en tu data así:

```
window.Vue = require('vue'); 

const app = new Vue({

el: '#crud',         

created: function(){
    this.getvehiculos();
},

data: {
    vehiculos: []
},
methods: {
    getvehiculos function() {

        var urlprueba = 'choferes';
        axios.get(urlprueba).then(response =>{
        this.vehiculos = response.data
        }) 
    }
},


});
```

Comment: En caso que lo que planteas solucione el problema, debería ser cerrada esta pregunta por un error tipográfico.

Comment: he corregido el error, pero ahora me lo señala mas abajo  },
          32 |     methods: {
       > 33 |          getvehiculos function() {
               |                               ^

Comment: si estas usando webpack, entonces es getvehiculos() (sin function). Igual la pregunta deberia ser cerrada porque es un claro error tipografico en los dos casos. o en el peor de los casos OP no entiende la codificacion y habria que explicarle porque las cosas se escriben asi.

Comment: Es lo mismo que con el otro, te faltan los `:`, `getvehiculos: function()`.

Comment: Si, era un error tipografico, problema resuelto.Grcs